# Apache tomcat spring mvc webapp subida de archivos

Tags: java, mvc, spring, tomcat

Estoy creando una aplicación con Spring MVC, en la cual los usuarios suben archivos, entiendo que los archivos no pueden ubicarse dentro del proyecto puesto que esto haria mi archivo .WAR muy pesado ademas estos archivos se perderian si vuelvo a desplegar la aplicación.

Mi pregunta es:

¿En qué lugar explicitamente ubicarlos sin que se
pierdan al volver a desplegar la aplicación?se pueden ubicar dentro de
tomcat? o necesito otra herramienta.

Comment: A lo mejor y te sirve esta pregunta(inglés) hecha en SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847994/spring-mvc-save-uploaded-multipartfile-to-specific-folder

Comment: Puedes guardar como dice @Adrian menendez o guardarlos en la BBDD, a mi me gusta más, porque si ese war te lo llevas a otro servidor tendrías que copiarte tb los archivos, en cambio si apunta a una BBDD, basta con llevarte el war

Comment: Guardar los archivos en un servidor externo puede ser una buena opción, por ejemplo, si se trata de imágenes puedes guardar las misma en un servicio diseñado para ello, hay muchos gratuitos o de pago, de este modo no recargas la base de datos o el servidor, en tu BD solo deberás almacenar el enlace a dicho archivo.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes ubicar los archivos en la ruta del servidor que quieras, podrías hacer algo así en el controlador, suponiedo que tienes un fichero llamado `file`:

```
String uploadsDir = "<RUTA>";

if(! new File(uploadsDir).exists())
    new File(uploadsDir).mkdir();

String filePath = uploadsDir + "\\" + file.getOriginalFilename();

File dest = new File(filePath);

file.transferTo(dest);
```